# Going through each list in nested list

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I would like my code to go through each sublist in my list. But so far it only returns the first sublist.

Before creating this question I researched multiple answers on the previous questions regarding nested lists. But none really made sense in my case, to my understanding. I implement them and try them out to the best of my skills.

```
l = [['Empire:FourKingdoms:', '     US  FR  DE   GB', ' 208  96  42  149'], ['BigFarmMobileHarvest:', '     US   FR  DE   GB', ' 211  101  64  261'], ['AgeofLords:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['BattlePiratesHQ:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['CallofWar:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['Empire:AgeofKnights:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['Empire:MillenniumWars:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['eRepublik:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['GameofEmperors:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['GameofTrenches:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['ImperiaOnline:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['ImperialHero:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['MarsTomorrow:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['OneEpicKnight:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['SeasonsofWar:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['SIEGE:TITANWARS:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['SIEGE:WorldWarII:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['Skytopia-CityTycoon:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['Supremacy1914:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['TacticalHeroes2:Platoons:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['TwinShooter-Invaders:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['VEGAConflict:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00'], ['WarandPeace:', '     US   DE', ' 358  571'], ['WarCommander:RogueAssault:', '     US   FR   DE   GB', ' 373  579  297  407'], ['WorldatWar:WW2StrategyMMO:', 'US JP FR DE GB', '00 00 00 00 00']]
new_l = []
def name(x):
    for items in x:
        #print(items)
        for value in items:
            #print(value)
            s = " ".join(str(i) for i in items) # splits from list to sublists
            #cleans the whitespace, quation marks etc.
            no_list = re.sub("\[",'',s)
            no_list = re.sub("\]s",'',no_list)
            no_list = re.sub("\'" , '',no_list)
            no_list = re.sub("\'", '',no_list)
            #splits the string
            s1 = no_list.split(' ')
            #cleans up again
            a = list(filter(None, s1))

            # make items in list to dict
            pairs = len(a) // 2
            res = {a[0]: dict(zip(a[1:1+pairs], a[1+pairs:]))}
            new_l.append(res)
            return res

print(name(l))
```

(undesired) result:

```
{'Empire:FourKingdoms:': {'US': '208', 'FR': '96', 'DE': '42', 'GB': '149'}}
```

Funny thing is if I instead of "return res" say "print(res)"  I get what I desire, but everything is duplicated three times.

```
{'Empire:FourKingdoms:': {'US': '208', 'FR': '96', 'DE': '42', 'GB': '149'}}
{'Empire:FourKingdoms:': {'US': '208', 'FR': '96', 'DE': '42', 'GB': '149'}}
{'Empire:FourKingdoms:': {'US': '208', 'FR': '96', 'DE': '42', 'GB': '149'}}
{'BigFarmMobileHarvest:': {'US': '211', 'FR': '101', 'DE': '64', 'GB': '261'}}
{'BigFarmMobileHarvest:': {'US': '211', 'FR': '101', 'DE': '64', 'GB': '261'}}
{'BigFarmMobileHarvest:': {'US': '211', 'FR': '101', 'DE': '64', 'GB': '261'}}
...
```

So close but still so far.

I'm not sure why my code likes to play around with me.

(The code might also look hideous, but I'm still learning and aim to clean it up once it's done)

Comment: The return statement will run immediately after one run through the nested loop. The function will stop there, so you only get the 1 return value.

Comment: Interesting. So unindented print(res) once, and it worked. But I don't understand why print(res) works. So I don't actually need "new_l" and .append?

Comment: `print(res)` works because there is no return statement, so the procedure will carry out completely. If you replace that line with a return statement, only part of the function will be able to execute.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm still curious though, why does it loop every item three times?

Comment: the nested list is unnecessary and causes you to loop through each item 3 times. Will post solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the return statement causes only part of the algorithm to execute, stopping the function premature to your intended output.
Also, the nested list is unnecessary if you don't want it to be trebled. Just use one layer of the for loop.
Without changing the code itself too much:

```py
import re
new_l = []
def name(x):
    for items in x:
        s = " ".join(str(i) for i in items) # splits from list to sublists
        #cleans the whitespace, quation marks etc.
        no_list = re.sub("\[",'',s)
        no_list = re.sub("\]s",'',no_list)
        no_list = re.sub("\'" , '',no_list)
        no_list = re.sub("\'", '',no_list)
        #splits the string
        s1 = no_list.split(' ')
        #cleans up again
        a = list(filter(None, s1))
        # make items in list to dict
        pairs = len(a) // 2
        res = {a[0]: dict(zip(a[1:1+pairs], a[1+pairs:]))}
        new_l.append(res)
    return new_l

print(name(l))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought by having two loops that's how you iterated through nested lists, but apparently not. Thanks a lot, sir! Any ideas on how to get the dictionary out of the list? :)

Comment: @doomdaam you can just refer to each dictionary in the list by the indexes in the list itself.